# Invalid duration specification with FFMPEG - what could be the reason?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using a command like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 00.11.10 -map 0 output.mp4
```

I get:

```
Invalid duration specification for t: 00.11.10
```

Similar error for `-to` and `-ss`.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your duration format is the problem, you have used dot (`.`) instead of colon (`:`).

Duration may be a number in seconds, or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form.

Try `-t 670` or `-t 00:11:10` instead.